# How to download and view pdf files stored on parse.com on android list view

Tags: android, parse-platform

i am currently developing an android app to download and view pdf files from parse.com server in a list or gridview in android there is no requirement to save them just to view them using google docs and a webview, but i unable to figure out how to do that any help is highly appreciated.

```
ArrayList<ParseObject> list = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Mobiles"); 
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() 
{ 
@Override public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) 
 { if (e == null) 
 { 
 list = (ArrayList<ParseObject>) objects; 
 mMyadapter = new MyAdapter(context, list); 
 } 
 else { 
     } 
 }); 
ParseFile pf = (ParseFile) list.get(position).get("pdffiles"); 
pf.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() 
{ @Override 
public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) 
{ if (e == null) 
{ //    add to list view } else { Log.d("debug", "bad"); } } });
}
 }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get the Url of the file and then pass the link to google docs.

parse documentation doesn't mention that you can get the file Url, I think this because they think every developer by common sense will expect that essential and primitive is exists.

```
ParseFile pdfUrl=((ParseFile)list.get(position).get("pdffiles")).getUrl();
String googleDocsUrl = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + pdfUrl;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(googleDocsUrl),"text/html");

startActivity(intent);
```